# Com o que devo me preocupar ao criar uma Tabela Particionada no SQL Server?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, database-partitioning

Me foi sugerido particionar a principal tabela do meu sistema para conseguir melhorar a performance de algumas consultas.

O dev que fez a sugestão sugeriu usar a informação do `ano` de cadastro do registro para particionar, pois como o sistema não esta funcionando há mais de *10 anos* haveriam poucas partições (o que segundo ele seria o ideal).

Mas pelo que eu entendi do funcionamento da partição, seria mais proveitoso eu particionar usando o identificador da empresa/órgão a qual pertence o registro (*são aproximadamente 300 diferentes*). Pensei em fazer assim pois na maioria das consultas essa a chave é utilizada. Mas eu não sei se posso ou devo fazer isso.

Quais são os cuidados, e com o que devo me preocupar ao particionar uma tabela no `SQL Server`?

---

Sobre a tabela, trata-se de uma tabela bem volumosa com mais de um milhão de registros que possui relacionamento em diferentes níveis com grande parte das outras tabelas do sistema.

---

**UPDATE**:

Após ler os links postados nos comentários, vi que seria inviável nessa situação particionar usando o identificador da empresa/órgão (devido a quantidade de partições geradas) e que não traria resultados particionar por ano já que não uso esse parâmetro nas consultas.

Mesmo que não se aplique a essa situação em especifico, ficaria feliz em obter uma resposta esclarecedora sobre **o que devo me preocupar na hora de criar uma tabela particionada?**

Comment: Tem uma ótima leitura aqui, pode ajudar com suas dúvidas: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes

Comment: Sobre particionamento de tabelas, eis compilação sobre o assunto: https://www.brentozar.com/sql/table-partitioning-resources/

Comment: 1 milhão de linhas é _trocado_. Sugiro que verifique outras formas de otimizar, antes de decidir pelo particionamento. // Não se preocupe com a maioria das consultas mas sim com as que consomem mais recursos. // Particionar por ano somente será vantajoso se as consultas filtrarem também por data.

Comment: @JoséDiz sobre particionar por ano tbm tenho a mesma opinião. As consultas que ficam mais lenta não são exatamente as feitas diretamente nessa tabela. Mas outras que tbm envolvem ela...

Comment: Depois das leituras recomendadas já praticamente desisti de particionar essa tabela. Mas ainda busco uma resposta definitiva sobre a minha duvida

Comment: Olá, da uma lida nesse artigo da Microsoft e vê se te ajuda https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15